# Python Pandas: add list to df of different len

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following list of len 52:

```
cw = list(range(1,53))
```

I want to add this list to my df of len 104

I use:

```
df.insert(0,"CW",cw, True)
```

This results in:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I want the list to be added to the first 52 rows of the df and then, starting againg from 1, to the second 52 rows.

Comment: You could just change the definition of your list: `cw = list(range(1,53)) + list(range(1,53))`  or even: `cw = list(range(1,53)) * 2`

Comment: `df.insert(0,"CW",cw*2, True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code by adding `+cw`:

```
df.insert(0,"CW",cw+cw, True)
```

or by adding `* 2`:

```
df.insert(0,"CW",cw * 2, True)
```